# List non-mutating method

Tags: python, mutable

Is there in python any method that instead of mutate the original list it returns a new object?

In JavaScript there is at least one:

```
const originalArray = [1,2,3]
originalArray.concat(4) // returns a new array
```

Comment: `newarray = originalArray + [4]`

Comment: const is not a Python keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, this will return a new list:

```
originalArray = [1,2,3]
originalArray + [4]
```

Or if you want to create a new copy of the list use slices:

```
originalArray[:]
```

List comprehensions will also create a new list:

```
[x for x in originalArray]
```

This is yet another way:

```
import copy
copy.copy(originalArray)
```

And there's also the built-in `copy()` method, as shown in Ronald's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74071252/201359).

Comment: Or the built-in copy() method

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the copy method:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = list1.copy()

list1 is list2, list1 == list2
```

returns

```
(False, True)
```

Showing that you have new object with the same content.